# Codeigniter 2 using a library in a loop

Tags: php, codeigniter, twig

I have an issue I keep hitting the wall on and I need some suggestions on the best way around this.

I got a loop that grabs data from my model, but within that loop, I have to validate it against a library, but I cant seem to find a good way to do that.

for example, I got a model method that looks similar to this:

```
public function GetUserList() {

    $this->db->select('username, email, joindate, rank')->from('user');
    $query = $this->db->get();

   //loop through data and bind to an array.
   foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $users[] = $row;
    }

    return $users;
}
```

when the page loads the user will see a list of users and their info, but some users don't want their email address to be shown, we then have to use the user library to fetch the settings for that user and see if we should hide that email or not.

the only solution i found was to use a helper function as a detour, but I feel that is going to bite me in the future duplicating things like that.

the other issue I found was once you created the library it didn't restart the object as a new one (like it would in vanilla PHP).

I'm hoping someone has a good way to resolve a setback like this.

One last item, if it makes a difference, I'm also using Twig to handle my views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to load every library file using the `load()` function. The `load()` function is for loading a single instance in the global (CI) namespace. If you want to work with a collection of objects, you should `require` the file like you normally would in PHP.

Comment: I sorta assumed that would be the case. though still how do i filter out the data?

Comment: Doing a join in your query is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally join on your preferences table if possible.  That way you wouldn't have to do a separate query for every single user.